# How to improve code with several route parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-routing

I listen route parameters in component:

```
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.has("a")) {
        this.openA(params.get("a"));
      }

      if (params.has("b")) {
        this.openVersion(params.get("b"));
      }

      if (params.has("action")) {
        if (params.get("action") == "c") {
          this.createC();
        }

        if (params.get("action") == "d") {
          this.createD();
        }
      }

       ... and a lot of others
});
```

As you can see it is spagetti routing code, how do you solve this issue?

Comment: You can use a `switch` for  `params.has()`. Also use `===` instead of `==`. It's not that bad, there is still some structure in it if you only call `params.has()` and `params.get()`

Comment: is it possible: `case iparams.has("a") && params.get("action") == "c": break;` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using two conditions in one case unless you do it everywhere in the `switch`, but can you write it? Yes you can.